# Can you get merged attributes for a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, attributes

Say I have the following set of classes, is it possible for the attributes of DerivedClass to be merged? Currently if I use the GetType().GetCustomAttributes()method passing in true for inheritance it takes the highest attributes in the inheritance structure.

i.e. [Another("Bob")] and [My(16)]

Is it possible for the attributes to be merged? So I would end up with two attributes of [My(16, "Male")] and [Another("Bob")]

I don't mean to say that I would specify an attribute of [My(16, "Male")] but rather I would be returned an attribute with an Age of 16 and a Gender of Male.

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{

    public MyAttribute(int age)
    {
        Age = age;
    }

    public MyAttribute(int age, string gender)
    {
        Age = age;
        Gender = gender;
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

}

public class AnotherAttribute : Attribute
{

    public AnotherAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

[My(12, "Male")]
[Another("Bob")]
public class BaseClass
{
}

[My(16)]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to mark attributes as "allow multiple" to achieve this?

Comment: @Craig: updated my answer and may provide more information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple instances of the same attribute on an entity (this is an option on the `AttributeUsageAttribute` applied to your attribute). When you get attributes on a type, you can get all the attributes applied to the inheritance chain.

However there is nothing in the standard tools that will take two attribute instances and make one.

(In theory a post processor that re-wrote the MSIL could do this.)

Comment: Thanks Richard that gets me a little closer. I was expecting to be able to get all the attributes and then have to merge them myself but was a little confused when I only got 2 attributes back so I couldn't even merge myself!

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't believe any of the behavior you're inquiring about would depend on the `AttributeUsage` attribute which should be decorating your attribute classes (*it looks like I could be wrong*). Nor do I see where any attribute would be getting merged. Each attribute is a representation of a class in it's own right. Each attribute class should return it's own data. I would expect `DerivedClass.GetCustomAttributes()` to return three separate references for each attribute - 2 from the base class, and 1 for itself.

Try setting the AttributeUsage on the 'MyAttribute' to allow multiple. It may not be merging them, but taking the 'latest' version of the attribute.

I just thought of something else that could be causing the mysterious disappearing act. You may have to go after the `base` class to get the *original* attribute? You could try that:

```
base.GetType().GetCustomAttributes();
```

I did some digging and here is what the `AttibuteUsage` will do and could be causing you to only see one of the `MyAttribute` classes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
```

I was close in my statement earlier about using `AttributeUsage`; however, it is the `Inherited` named parameter that will limit visibility to the base class' `MyAttribute` decoration. Try specifying `Inherited = true` and see what you get.

Comment: GetCustomAttributes is only returning two attributes. The AnotherAttribute from BaseClass and MyAttribute from DerivedClass. I was expecting 3 classes which would have allowed me to merge the attributes myself.