# How can I combine two C# annotations into a "shortcut" annotation?

Tags: c#, annotations, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I've found it's a handy pattern to declare inspector variables (set by reflection or magic by Unity) as private and to annotate them with the `[SerializeField]` attribute. This keeps programming interfaces clean while allowing the Inspector to set the fields. I also use Resharper, and to let it know that these field are set implicitly I use the attribute `[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]`.

This leaves me with a lot of variables as a brick wall of annotations where finding the variables takes unnecessary effort:

```
[SerializeField, UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]
private Transform headingLabel;
[SerializeField, UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]
private Transform coolDataLabel;
[SerializeField, UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]
private GameObject yetAnotherLabelToMakeThePoint;
```

How can I combine these annotations into a single annotation `[PrivateInspectorVariable]` with identical behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2216822/315544) on Stack Overflow:

> However there is nothing in the standard tools that will take two attribute instances and make one.
>
> (In theory a post processor that re-wrote the MSIL could do this.)

My suggestion would be to write your attributes on separate lines and use space to make them easier to read:

```
[SerializeField]
[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]
private Transform headingLabel;

[SerializeField]
[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]
private Transform coolDataLabel;

[SerializeField]
[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]
private GameObject yetAnotherLabelToMakeThePoint;
```

Comment: So, probably not possible, this is what I'm starting to think too.  I'm going to leave the question in case anyone has a solution. (I prefer oneliners here because all the attributes here are exactly identical and there are 20-30 variables going on - shorter scrolls :D)

Comment: Yeah, it's completely a matter of preference there. What works for you is the best option. Perhaps somebody will modify the language specification to allow compound attributes, but it's unlikely, as I believe that would require multiple inheritance.